# Why can't I get the natural width of my image?

Tags: jquery

The URL of the image whose natural size I want to get is stored as data tag like so:

```
<div class="background_one" data-image="//localhost:3000/my_project/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/case_2_desk-1.jpg"></div>
```

With jQuery I retrieve this URL, create an image object to which I assign the URL as source, then get the size of this image object.

```
$('.background_one').each(function(){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = $(this).data('image');
    alert('width: ' + image.naturalWidth + ' and height: ' + image.naturalHeight);
});
```

It should work, but it doesn't. The `alert()` displays "width: 0 and height: 0". Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
image.onload = function() { console.log(this.height); };
```

Have you added your code inside a document.ready function like so:

```
$(document.ready(function(){ // your code });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it hasn't been loaded yet.

You need to wait for the `load` event before you can access the image dimensions.

```
$('.background_one').each(function(){
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
       alert('width: ' + image.naturalWidth + ' and height: ' + image.naturalHeight);
    };
    image.src = $(this).data('image');
});
```

Comment: image.onload(function({}); seems to never fire.

Comment: @drake035 yes you are right. i was thinking in jquery syntax. corrected it.

Comment: This is the right answer, thanks a lot! But I realise @Kaloyan already had the right answer 1 minute before you so to be fair I validated his answer..

Comment: @drake035 not an issue.